How do Bible scholars interpret Prov 17:17?
We read in Proverbs 17:17 (ESV):

A friend loves at all times, and a brother is born for a time of adversity.

That could be understood  in different ways. One possible interpretation  is that you should rely on your kith and kin to stand by you at the time of adversity and not on a friend who may otherwise express love for you. Another interpretation is that a blood relative may not always express love for you, but will support you in adversity. Yet another is that it is not necessary to 'like'  a person in order to stand by him/ her in adversity.  Given that Greek language had a number of distinct words for love, the intent of Prov 17:17 is not clear in English Versions . My question is : How do Bible scholars interpret Prov 17:17 ?

Here is my very literal translation of Prov 17:17 -

[at] all times, a friend loves; and a brother is born for adversity

Note the parallelism which I set out more clearly below:


a friend loves at all times (ie without ceasing)
a brother is born for adversity


This is teaching a fundamental truth about true friendship: just as a brother cannot cease to be a brother in difficult/adverse times, so a true friend does not abandon the relationship (of friendship) under any circumstances.
That is, a good friend is as unchanged by circumstances any more that difficulties change familial ties.  Benson is succinct here:

Proverbs 17:17. A friend loveth at all times — A sincere and hearty
friend not only loves in prosperity, but also in adversity, when false
friends forsake us; and a brother — Who is so, not only by name and
blood, but by brotherly affection; is born for adversity — Was sent
into the world for this among other ends, that he might comfort and
relieve his brother in his adversity.

APPENDIX - Greek LXX Translation
For comparison, here is the LXX translation:

εἰς πάντα καιρὸν φίλος ὑπαρχέτω σοι, ἀδελφοὶ δὲ ἐν ἀνάγκαις χρήσιμοι
ἔστωσαν, τούτου γὰρ χάριν γεννῶνται.

Brenton translates this as:

Have thou a friend for every time, and let brethren be useful in
distress; for on this account are they born.

This is (as is often the case) a somewhat paraphrastic translation.

+1 But since the OP asked about Greek, how would you translate the LXX?

@DanFefferman - OK, I will add something about the LXX and Greek translation

There are many ways to translate and interpret this verse. Since this was originally written in Hebrew, I turned first to a  Jewish scholar. Rashi understands it to mean that in times of trail a friend is reborn as a brother:

At the time of adversity, the
friend will be born to you as a brother, to help you and to
participate in your adversity.

The Pulpit commentary, while not committing itself, begins with an opinion that agrees with the above:

A real friend
loves his friend in prosperity and adversity; yea, he is more than a
friend in time of need - he is a brother, as affectionate and as
trusty as one connected by the closest ties of relationship (comp.
Proverbs 18:24).

However Pulpit also points out that the Septuagint tends in another direction:

"Have thou a friend for every crisis, and let brethren be useful in
adversities; for for this they are made."

The Geneva Study Bible agrees with Rashi and the first opinion given in Pulpit, concluding that a friend:

...is more than a friend, even a brother that helps in time of
adversity.

So too Keil and Delitzsch, who rely on the Hebrew:

The relation of a friend may deepen itself into a spiritual, moral
brotherhood... The friend meant in 17a is a true friend. Of no other
is it said that he loves בּכל־עת, i.e., makes his love manifest; and
also the article in הרע not only here gives to the word more body, but
stamps it as an ideal-word: the friend who corresponds to the idea of
such an one.

Conclusion:  I would conclude that in the translation of the Greek version (as cited above), the plain sense of the text is that a brother is more reliable than a friend in difficult times.  But scholars who consider the Hebrew as a better witness tend to understand the meaning to be that a friend shows his true worth in times of adversity, and thus becomes a brother.

Proverbs 18:24 A man that hath friends must shew himself friendly: and there is a friend that sticketh closer than a brother. (Prov. 18:24 KJV)

Thanks, Dan Fefferman . Proverbs 18:19 also says: " A brother offended is harder to be won than a strong city: and their contentions are like the bars of a castle. " If that is a sequel to 17:17 (ii), the term brother refers to blood relatives only.
